# How can I filter detections by PolygonZone in Roboflow supervision

Tags: python, yolov8, roboflow

I have an intelligence created by a roboflow notebook and I run it from my web camera but I want the detections to be only in a polygonal area and not in the entire camera.
they say I can do it with

```
import supervision as sv
zone = sv.PolygonZone(...)
detections = sv.Detections(...)
mask = zone.trigger(detections=detections)
detections = detections[mask]
```

Could you give me an example of how to fill it out

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.